# Como habilitar o botão próximo do Android para ir para um campo específico?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um formulário com 4 EditTexts e quando eu terminasse de preencher o primeiro e clicasse no próximo eu precisava ir para o terceiro campo. Alguém sabe como setar isso para o próximo ir para um EditText específico? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: MeuEditText.requestFocus() não serve?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o atributo `nextFocusDown` resolve seu problema, exemplo:

```
<EditText
    ... <!-- Demais atributos -->
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/proximo_edit_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/proximo_edit_text"
    .... <!-- Demais atributos -->
    />
```

Quando o usuário clicar no "Next" do teclado físico, ele vai mudar o foco para o `EditText` cujo `id` seja o valor do `nextFocusDown`.

Acho que essa documentação oficial sobre [Supporting Keyboard Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html) pode te ajudar com outras questões.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solução funciona (não há necessidade de adicionar android:focusable="true"\android:focusableInTouchMode="true"):

```
final EditText userEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userEditText);

userEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            Log.i(TAG, "userEditText lost focus");
            if(null == m_requestFocus){
                m_userName = userEditText.getText().toString();
                if(m_userName.length() < 6){
                    m_signUpText.setText("Username should have at least 6 characters");
                    m_requestFocus = userEditText;
                }
                else{
                    checkUserNameExists();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(null != m_requestFocus & m_requestFocus != userEditText){
                v.clearFocus();
                m_requestFocus.requestFocus();
                m_requestFocus = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```